# How to partial search Elasticsearch datastore

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to be able to search elasticsearch for either an exact match, or a partial search.

my input could be either `name: Foobar` and in my list of results, I should be able to see any names matching `Foobar`. Although if I enter `Fo*` I want to get back any names matching `Fo`such as Foreman, Foobill etc.

At the moment, if I search my database I just get back all the results to do with `name` regardless of what the string looks like.

My code:

```
const { body: clientBody, ...rest } = await client.search({
      filter_path: 'hits.hits._source',
      body: {
        query: {
          bool: {
            should: [
              {
                match: eventBody,
              },
              {
                wildcard: eventBody,
              },
            ],
            minimum_should_match: 1,
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

EventBody is just an object as mentioned above - i.e. `name: Fo*`

Comment: Can you share your mapping for name? you can use ES new keyword field type WildCard field that is optimised for your situation, for more information check here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/keyword.html#wildcard-field-type

Comment: hey @Kaveh, the name field was just an example. I input the field through postman as a simple object of ```{ foo: bar }``` and try to pull the information back through the search query above. I can get it to work for pulling multiple fields, but not for just a single one as mentioned above

Comment: @Kaveh Also, am I right in thinking that the documentation is saying that for a field to be searched using the ```wildcard``` field that it must be indexed with a type of wildcard first?

Comment: yes you will need to index it as a wildcard field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option would be to use wildcard field new keyword data type introduced by Elasticsearch. For more information check official documentation of Elastic about wildcard field [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/keyword.html#wildcard-field-type).